# google app script sending mail as PDF issue

Tags: google-apps-script

A script was working fine 6 months ago and now is creating me some issue when sending a doc as pdf...-> My pdf loose his layout.

I am not loosing the doc's layout when i send the mail manually using (from the menu) file ->Email as attachment -> choose pdf

but when i use this (a script.) i've got 25 extra pages and i loose the oirginal layout of the document.

```
var fileq = DriveApp.getFileById('17Fj7JfYkQk9blablabla');
MailApp.sendEmail('somemail', "Attachment example", "blablabla", { name: 'Automatic Emailer Script', attachments: [fileq.getAs(MimeType.PDF)] });
```

What is going on ?

thanks for help,

another problem:
The problem occurs even when downloading more than 1 doc in pdf at time...very wierd..

The only thinhs who works in extract 1 file to pdf at time manually...all other stuff (scripting or manually) just modifiy the layout.

May be this problem is related only for big file..my docs are 20 to 25 pages long.
Who knows ?
Thanks for help anyway

Comment: WHen you download the document as PDF from Google Documents File Menu, do you see this issue? If yes, then we might have to report this issue to Google Docs team. Consider to make a copy of the document and then use it with script and check if you still see the issue.

Comment: no.
But when choosing multiple file (from the drive menu) yes i've got issue.
When coding it..i have got issue too..I use this for 1 year (by code i mean) without any issue...with 800 docs in 25 folders.

I've got issue from last week approximately without changing nothing to my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem did not ocurr with me. You can see the sample [here](https://script.google.com/d/1N9MQDZC20QSXAla-3_FSTSFZxdEMjQy_Kpmr-pnBx9o9UxixEiu8cPu8/edit?usp=sharing).

Please change the document ID in this script and run again sending to my mail and I will check the results.

Answer (score 0):

It adding to me 24 extra page..changing the layout of the entire original document.